# Wireless Bridge with Tenda and D-link

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Dlink-615 Hardware Rev:D1 connected to my modem and I was wondering whether or not I could use my spare tenda w311r as a wireless bridge. The tenda supports WDS but the DLink doesn't, does this mean I am unable to run a bridge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Bu you can still can use your w311r as an independent access point, if you can strip a cable and connect a switch to the location where you need wireless connectivity, if that is what you are intending to achieve.